# How to decide the MySQL capacity for Hive Metastore DB?

Tags: amazon-web-services, hadoop, hive, hcatalog, hive-metastore

I'm setting up external metastore(MySQL) for the hive service in EMR. I'd like to know if there is any best practice or documentation available on parameter for deciding the RDS(MySQL instance) capacity.

FYI : I found few vendors([cloudera](https://docs.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-8-x/topics/cdh_ig_hive_metastore_configure.html)) giving spec on metastore memory requirement. But i'm not able to find anything concrete on deciding the RDS capacity.

Comment: Not for that use case but we used mysql compatible `aurora serverless` which provides on-demand, auto-scaling configuration with it. you upscale/downscale according to your needs.

Comment: @Ersoy I believe AWS Glue is more commonly used as a Hive Metastore

Comment: @cricket_007 i am not so familiar with the domain, my suggestion was based on mysql alternative for a manageable capacity alternative - thanks for the suggestion

Comment: The question doesn't have enough details. How many Hive databases or tables are you going to make? How many partitions will each table have? What types of schemas are you going to be storing? Will you be adding large commented desciptions to the metadata of each table? ... All these take storage on the metastore. But start with 100G and monitor it. It's not hard to expand or shard RDS

Comment: @Ersoy - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-hive-metastore-glue.html